# java-POST method 415 Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, backbone.js

I have java EE project.I used Spring Hibernate for server side and Backbone,RequireJS,Jquery for client side on this project.I'm trying to save with POST method but HTTP 415 Error return.

My Get method works fine. I tested it on Postman.

My url: localhost:8080/rest/travel

**EDITED**

My Resource Class

```
    @Component
@Path("/travel")
public class TravelResource {

        @Autowired
        private TravelService travelService;
       @Autowired
      private UserService userService;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON+ ";charset=UTF-8")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public TravelDTO save(TravelDTO dto) {
        dto.setUser(userService.get(dto.getUser().getUserID()));
          dto.setTravelStart(new Date());
          dto.setTravelEnd(new Date());

          return travelService.save(dto);
        }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{travelID}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public TravelDTO edit(@PathParam("travelID") int id, TravelDTO dto) {
        dto.setUser(userService.get(dto.getUser().getUserID()));
        dto.setTravelStart(new Date());
        dto.setTravelEnd(new Date());

        return travelService.edit(id,dto);
        }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{travelID}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public int delete(@PathParam("travelID") int id) {
        travelService.delete(id);
        return id;
        }
    @GET
    @Path("/{travelID}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public TravelDTO get(int id) {
        return travelService.get(id);
        }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public List<TravelDTO> getAll() {
        return travelService.getAll();

        }

    @GET
    @Path("/search/{travelStart}/{travelEnd}/" )
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
    public List<TravelDTO> search(@PathParam("travelStart") Date travelStart,
                                  @PathParam("travelEnd") Date travelEnd )
    {
        return travelService.search(travelStart,travelEnd);
    }

}
```

My DTO Class

```
public class TravelDTO implements Serializable {

    public TravelDTO convert(Travel model) {
        this.setTravelID(model.getTravelID());
        this.setTravelCost(model.getTravelCost());
        this.setTravelStart(model.getTravelStart());
        this.setTravelEnd(model.getTravelEnd());
        this.setLocation(model.getLocation());
        this.setTravelPurpose(model.getTravelPurpose());
       this.setProjectCode(model.getProjectCode());
       this.setUser(new UserDTO().convert(model.getUser()));
        return this;
    }
        private int travelID;

       private String projectCode;

        private Date travelStart;

        private Date travelEnd;

        private String Location;

        private float travelCost;

        private UserDTO user;

        private String travelPurpose;

    public UserDTO getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserDTO user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getProjectCode() {
        return projectCode;
    }

    public void setProjectCode(String projectCode) {
        this.projectCode = projectCode;
    }

    public int getTravelID() {
            return travelID;
        }

        public void setTravelID(int travelID) {
            this.travelID = travelID;
        }

        public Date getTravelStart() {
            return travelStart;
        }

        public void setTravelStart(Date travelStart) {
            this.travelStart = travelStart;
        }

        public Date getTravelEnd() {
            return travelEnd;
        }

        public void setTravelEnd(Date travelEnd) {
            this.travelEnd = travelEnd;
        }

        public String getLocation() {
            return Location;
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            Location = location;
        }

        public float getTravelCost() {
            return travelCost;
        }

        public void setTravelCost(float travelCost) {
            this.travelCost = travelCost;
        }

        public String getTravelPurpose() {
            return travelPurpose;
        }

        public void setTravelPurpose(String travelPurpose) {
            this.travelPurpose = travelPurpose;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        TravelDTO travelDTO = (TravelDTO) o;

        return travelID == travelDTO.travelID;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return travelID;
    }
}
```

MY SERVICE CLASS

```
@Service
public class TravelService {
        @Autowired
        private TravelDAO travelDAO;

        @Transactional
        @ResponseBody
        public TravelDTO save(TravelDTO dto) {
            Travel station = new Travel();
            station.convert(dto);
            try {
                station = travelDAO.persist(station);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            return dto.convert(station);
        }

        @Transactional
        @ResponseBody
        public TravelDTO edit(int id, TravelDTO dto) {
            Travel travel = new Travel();
            try {
                travel.convert(dto);
                travelDAO.merge(travel);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            return dto.convert(travel);
        }

        @Transactional
        @ResponseBody
        public boolean delete(int id) {
            try {
                Travel travel = travelDAO.find(id);
                travelDAO.remove(travel);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public TravelDTO get(int id) {
            Travel travel;
            try {
                travel = travelDAO.find(id);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            return new TravelDTO().convert(travel);
        }

        public List<TravelDTO> getAll() {
            List<TravelDTO> travelDTOList = new ArrayList<TravelDTO>();
            try {
                for (Travel travel : travelDAO.findAll())
                    travelDTOList.add(new TravelDTO().convert(travel));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            return travelDTOList;
        }

        public List<TravelDTO> search(Date startTime, Date endTime)
                                      {
            List<TravelDTO> travelDTOList = new ArrayList<TravelDTO>();
            try {
                for (Travel station : travelDAO.search(startTime, endTime))
                    travelDTOList.add(new TravelDTO().convert(station));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            return travelDTOList;
        }




}
```

My data :

```
model:{"Location":"s","projectCode":"51","travelPurpose":"s","travelStart":"1.1.1","travelEnd":"8.12.2016"}
```

Network TAB

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07cHU.png)

Comment: 415 Unsupported Media Type
The request entity has a media type which the server or resource does not support. For example, the client uploads an image as image/svg+xml, but the server requires that images use a different format. can you post the message which is being sent?

Comment: Added my post data @MosheArad

Comment: You should add the DTO object structure here. Model class is not required.

Comment: @gaganbm added dto and service

Comment: I have added the answer. You can try through curl or postman, and set proper headers.

Comment: I added Context-Type:application/json to header on postman and post data.Error changed now 500 @gaganbm

Comment: May be it is a typo at your end. It is not `Context-type`, it is `Content-type`. Secondly, 500 could mean anything, like it is not able to save it in the database, or may be a null pointer exception somewhere! But the original problem of `415 media type` seems to be solved.

Comment: no, if i add "Context-Type:application/json" to postman header, 415 error solved.But my code still 415 error @gaganbm

Comment: What is `Context-Type` ? It should be `Content-Type`.

Comment: And if it is getting solved from `postman`, and you are still seeing the 415 error, then it must be a problem in the client that you are using. Your javascript client or curl or whatever.

Comment: writing mistake sorry @gaganbm

Comment: Like I said, if 415 error is gone from postman, but it is coming from any other client, you need to check how you are sending the request headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error's reason is this backbone code:

```
Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
```

If `Backbone.emulateJSON=true` , `Content-Type=   application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Now `Backbone.emulateJSON=false;` **Problem is solved!**

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying the call in POSTMAN add Content-Type: application/json as header parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP 415` comes when

```
The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload is in 
a format not supported by this method on the target resource.
```

Ref : https://httpstatuses.com/415

You need to set the request header correctly. As per the image you have attached, you are passing `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
But your code expects `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON+ ";charset=UTF-8")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public TravelDTO save(TravelDTO dto) {
        dto.setUser(userService.get(dto.getUser().getUserID()));
          dto.setTravelStart(new Date());
          dto.setTravelEnd(new Date());

          return travelService.save(dto);
        }
```

you're returning:  `return travelService.save(dto);`

and **you declared that you're returning an HTTP JSON**,

then just add to your controller the annotation `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`.

or just add to your method the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Comment: I'm using Rest.So i have no controller class.I have just (model, service, resource,dao and dto) But i am added @ResponseBody to the POST method but same 415 error continued

Comment: What do you mean "I have no controller"? if you don't use controllers with Spring how do you expect from your server to receive requests from end users?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/berat703/1b54549eecfc4e09534fe1b24e824591 
 .My Service class expect from my server to receive requests form end users.Should i do delete "@Service" and add "@RestController" ?

Comment: i don't find the solution.Sorry for disturb :(

Answer (score 0):

add following to your maven please:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```